# Is every input port of some microcontroller an interrupt?

Tags: c, microcontroller, interrupt

I was learning about interrupts and came here to see if someone can help me!

A) I understand that the interrupt is the electrical signal sent by some external hardware to the processor, via one of the input ports.

B) I understand that in some MCU's more than one input port are "attached" to only one interrupt.

Can exist an useful input port in a MCU that is not linked to any interrupt at all?

Answer (score 3):

> A) I understand that the interrupt is the electrical signal sent by 
>   some external hardware to the processor, via one of the input ports.

That is surely one class of interrupt, sure, as long as you understand that 'external hardware to the processor' can mean 'internal to the controller chip' - many MCU have extensive integrated peripherals.

> B) I understand that in some MCU's more than one input port are
>   "attached" to only one interrupt.

Yes - that is not uncommon.  The intrrupt-handler then has to poll the port to find out which GPIO/whatever pin generated the interrupt.

> Can exist an useful input port in a MCU that is not linked to any
>   interrupt at all?

Sure, especially on 'trivial' controllers that do not require high-performace IO and have no RTOS.

Even higher-performance MCU apps may poll for sundry reasons.  One common example is reading keypads.  The input rate is very low and the mechanical switches need to be debounced.  Fastening every KB read line to an interrupt line may cause unwanted multiple interrupts.  Such iputs are better polled, though even then, a timer interrupt often handles the polling.

Comment: But even on controllers that do not require high-performance or have no RTOS, all those external hardwares are still sending electrical signals to the processor. If the interrupt is this electrical signal, how can they not have interrupt?

Comment: The interrupts have to be set up for each peripheral.  Just getting an interrupt to happen at all is often a struggle.  GPIO pins have to be set up as inputs, maybe an input mask added to specify wich pins generate the interrupts.  The GPIO interrupts for that port need turning on.  The vectored interrupt controller mask/s have to be set up.  The interupt vector table entry loaded.  If you get all that right, then your interrupt handler may get entered, (and, first time, crash immediate).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is probably "yes," but it depends on the microcontroller architecture.  There's no guarantee that one vendor's MCU will behave the same as any other (with respect to interrupts, ports, or anything else).  If you're tasked with learning a particular MCU, then learn it, live it.

Answer (score 1):

You house may have only one doorbell button.  But pretty much anyone can use it for whatever reason.  UPS there is a package.  neighbor kid to play with your kid.  someone trying to sell something and so on.    A processor is no different.  To reduce latency newer designs may have multiple interrupt signals on the core so that the handler doesnt have to do as much if any work to figure out who caused the interrupt.  Kind of like having ringtones for every person on your phone, so you can tell without looking who is calling.  Vs. one ringtone for everyone and you have to look.

Do not confuse external gpio ports on the chip with interrupt lines, they are not.  they are general purpose I/O.  they might have a way to be used as interrupts or not, depends on the design of the chip.  Again as with the doorbell on your house, there are many things, technically all of them are within the chip (microcontroller), that create interrupts.  Because software has to setup handlers before it can...handle...interrupts, all sources of interrupts are disabled at first, and only the ones software enabled have the ability to actually reach the core and cause an interrupt.  Logic in the chip. so you may have an interrupt signal tied to the uart receiver and you might enable that.  You might have one for the tx buffer, when it is empty interrupt.  but you have to enable those before the processor can get an interrupt.  there is a small section of logic that does fire an interrupt every time one of those events occurs, but that signal is gated and cannot reach the core, blocked by logic you control.

You can have timers in the mcu, that interrupt you when they roll over or count to zero.  But you have to not only setup the timer to do that with software, you also have to enable the interrupt from making it across the chip from the timer to the processor core.

And yes sometimes the gpio peripheral has a way to interrupt the processor as well.  as with everything else you have to with software setup the peripheral and define what interrupts you want and you have to enable them across the chip.

There are more different ways of doing this than there are companies making chips as they dont always do it the same way across their product lines.  But generally at a minimum there is an interrupt enable on the peripheral end, one or many depending on the peripheral and features, that you have to enable in order for that signal to leave that peripheral on its way to the core.  And there is often an interrupt controller peripheral or something built into the core or near it that takes all the dozens or hundreds of individual interrupt connections in the chip and prioritizes them and orrs them into the one or few interrupt lines into the core.  you generally have to also enable the corresponding interrupt that matches the signal coming out of your peripheral to reach the processor core.  And then there is sometimes an interrupt enable in the core itself so that even if you have the peripheral enabled, the interrupt controller enabled for that one peripherals interrupt, you still cannot interrupt the processor unless the interrupt enable in the processor core is enabled.    That is the simple case, it can get more complicated if there are more layers of interrupt controllers along the way.   Well the simple case is when you have something like a cortex-m with dozens or hundreds of individual interrupt signals, still have interrupt enables on both ends and in the core, just easier to manage as you have dozens to hundreds of interrupt handlers instead of one mega handler for everything.

So dont confuse the pins on the chip as being interrupts, on older dedicated processors, like the 8088/86, sure that was the one interrupt pin.  But general purpose I/O sometimes called GPIO sometimes called ports, are just a peripheral, they are just pins you can make go high or low, they are not there to be interrupts although there may be a feature in that peripheral for that (or maybe there isnt).  And again interrupt signals go through logic gates and have to be enabled, by software, at a minimum on both ends of that signal, at the peripheral and at the interrupt controller.